# Codespaces failing to sync chmod=+x after git commit

Tags: codespaces, github-codespaces

The file is not executable:

```
git ls-tree HEAD
> 100644 blob <somekey> postCreateCommands.sh
```

The file is made executable:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x postCreateCommands.sh
git commit -m "fix: changing file permissions"
> mode change 100644 => 100755 .devcontainer/postCreateCommands.sh
```

However, when I hit "Sync Changes", Codespaces gets stuck syncing and the committed changes do not push.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the above workflow on VS code locally (i.e. git on my work laptop) without encountering the sync issue. I am unsure if the cause of this issue is a Codespaces bug or if there's something problematic about the container creation used for my Codespaces workspace, though I will not investigate further as I need to get on with my work.